# How to install Torch7 on windows7?

Tags: torch

Is there a way to install torch7 on Windows?
I query a lot of information, but for transplant Torch on WINDOWS no idea,
@Paul Kulchenko 
thank you very much

Comment: try to install `Cygwin` and execute with command line

Comment: Thank you very much.I will try it .could you got it installed and running on Windows?Do you have references or guidance files?

Answer (score 0):

You can find many guides on google search `Cygwin`.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjxEH_tr7e0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68PEBV9NpL8
https://www.physionet.org/physiotools/cygwin/

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to run a virtual Linux environment and install torch on it.
Cygwin may not perform as well